# How to pass the whole list in python string format?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Is there any way to pass the whole list in python string format

```
i=['John','10','A']

t="{:<10}| {:<10}| {:<10}"
print t.format("Name","Age","Grade")
# print t.format(i[0],i[1],i[2])
print t.format(i)
```

Instead of passing individual list values, I want to pass the whole list 
`print t.format(['John','10','A'])`  but this return `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `t.format(*i)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just **`unpack`** the list:

```
>>> i=['John','10','A']
>>> t="{:<10}| {:<10}| {:<10}"
>>> t.format(*i)
'John      | 10        | A         '
```

Comment: Can't we use `join` method here? Please clarify